# What should happen after git rebase --continue?

Tags: git

So I did a git rebase, got merge conflicts which I corrected and then did git adds on each file. At this point I did git rebase --continue and there were no more conflicts. But when I did a git status I saw there was nothing left to add. Did it create a commit already? I tried git commit but was not prompted for a commit comment. What should I do next?

**EDIT:** One further point -- when I did the rebase it said: "rebase in progress; onto 1be...000" and then it showed me many modified (merged) files (as well as stop when a merge conflict arose). I have looked at the commit 1be... and I see none of these automatically merged files or any that I resolved the conflicts for. So I would like to find these files since the manually modified files must be reviewed -- I need to specify a commit to be reviewed.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I am puzzled at what happens after all the merge conflicts are done, that is, I edited all the files and added them and the continued with the rebase until no more merge conflicts were reported. There are some files that I had never modified before that I expected to see if I did a commit which as mentioned I tried. My next step is to submit this commit for review but it doesn't seem like the reviewer will see all the files I merged.

Is it possible he doesn't need to see files that match those on the branch I was merging with?

Comment: if you fixed all conflicts and were left with nothing to commit, you can do `git rebase --skip`. This basically jumps over a commit if it's empty

Answer (score 4):

`git rebase --continue` will assume (will it check?) that you have fixed all merge conflicts and staged your index exactly how you want it to be.

It will then commit as though there hadn't been a merge conflict and continue the rebase process.

So yes, you already made the commit when you asked git to continue the rebase process.

---

Rebasing in git follows this basic process (I'm glossing over details here):

- For each commit you're rebasing:

  - apply the commit on top of the target commit

    - if merge conflict, stop, let user handle it
  - commit the staged index, reusing details from the commit it is rebasing

If applying a commit ends up with a merge conflict, git stops and lets you handle it. The index, as it is, when you ask git to continue the rebase is then used in the next step which will commit that index and continue with the next commit to rebase.

Comment: when i do a git log, i see a commit from a few days ago, so is this the commit that the files were added to? i would have expected the date to change since i think there were files in it i had not had before.

Comment: Is that a new question? When you do you execute `git log`? After the rebase has completed? Git rebase doesn't change the date or author of the commits it is rebasing, it only copies the commits to a new place in the history graph.

Comment: I mean it to be part of the same question: how to proceed once all the conflicts have been resolved. I listed all the files in the last commit and it does not show files i had to modify for the merge. Where would I see all the
 files that I edited to deal with merge conflicts?

Comment: After issuing `git rebase --continue`, a commit is made, you will have to inspect that commit. **Or**, you can issue `git status` **before** issuing `git rebase --continue` to see all those files. But after you've rebased, they're now part of the repository history.

Comment: re: *will assume (will it check?) that you have fixed all merge conflicts ...* It tries to make a new commit, and if there are still some conflicts, this step fails and it drops back to the shell to get the user to fix things up.

Comment: once there were no further conflicts i did not see a new commit.